# Is this relay circuit valid?

Tags: circuit-design, relay

This is my current circuit draft

[image: Circuit schematic]

Which had the SPST-NO symbol adapted from the supplier's symbol

[image: Relay symbol]

- I have not chosen any specific parts for diode, resistor or transistor.
- ALDP105W Relay datasheet: [here](https://datasheet.datasheetarchive.com/originals/distributors/Datasheets-DGA17/901128.pdf)

---

I am new to circuitry and PCB design, I was wondering if anyone could help me:

- Spot any issues or areas for concern
- Suggest some simple specs that I should look out for when buying a diode and transistor.

Thank you

**EDIT**:

The `GND` error flag seems to be invalid. I just have it connected to a screw terminal with a `PWR_FLAG` and the default KiCad NPN symbol as the emitter as `Open Emitter`

Comment: I commend your effort in not using those meaningless boxy symbols, but adapting graphical symbols that convey information needed to understand the schematic without reading every single piece of text on it. You understand that schematics are means of graphical engineering communication - that's an excellent start!

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Thank you! I can't stand them either. The graphical ones are so much easier. I hope I have translated the pins to the coils and contacts correctly too. Does the polarity with the coil matter very much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The circuit looks fine. A 2N3904 or other general purpose NPN would work since the coil current is 40mA at 5V which is pretty undemanding. Aim for a base current of 4mA with a Vbe of 0.95V for a 2N3904 or whatever your transistor's Vbe(sat) is, which gives you a base resistor of ~500 ohms. 510 or 470 would both work. For the diode, you want something that can handle at least the same current as the relay coil with at least the same reverse voltage rating, and fast. It shouldn't be hard to find a Schottky diode with these specs.